# Making changes to a Smart Group's distribution list persistent

Tags: macos, contacts

Is there a way to make changes to a Smart Group's distribution list persistent?

### Problem Description

In Address Book, I right-click on a Smart Group and select "Edit Distribution List".

[image: Smart Group in Address Book]

I then select a work address for a contact that has multiple email addresses.

[image: Edit Distribution List]

If I close the the "Edit Distribution List" menu and then go back into it, my change from home/other to work for that particular user did not persist.

The problem is that when I send an email using a smart group, I cannot ensure that everyone will receive the email to their work email address.

Any thoughts?

Comment: For what is worth, I experience the same behavior.

Comment: It's weird, look at this: http://www.macworld.com/article/158580/2011/03/groupsmailaddresses.html

Answer (score 1):

Distribution lists are not persisted for smart groups. On Lion, if you search Address Book help for "distribution list", you will see a page called "Select addresses for group members". Below step 2 is this piece of bad news: "You can't choose smart groups."

Some versions of OS X show smart groups in the `Edit Distribution List` window, but as of Lion, this is simply the user interface being misleading.

Speaking of Lion, users who use iCloud for contacts will see the `Edit Distribution List` menu item disabled, because this feature is not yet available with iCloud.